# How to extract the bound state energies with the Transfer Matrix Method?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, s-matrix-theory

On my quantum mechanics class this problem was introduced:

> Use the transfer matrix method to treat the bound states in a rectangular potential well. Extract the bound state energies from the transfer matrix and compare with theory (e.g. the bound states of a particle in a box). When is this comparison relevant? What happens as you vary the depth and size of the well?

How do I solved this? I am supposed to be able to plot this in MatLab and take some conclusion out. Me and my friends have been thinking in finding the transmission probability, in relation to its energy, with the transfer matrix and assume that where that peaks, equal one, there is a bound state. But we still need help with the calculations.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you had come up in terms of the code for the problem - currently going through the same problem.